# Wicket attach to existing Spring context

Tags: java, spring, wicket

I have a multi module Maven project. One of the modules is Spring backend  that has DAOs, transactional services and REST controllers for some angular clients (Ionic framework)
Now I find the need to add a new Wicket module for a web client. This module uses the first module as a dependency. When I start the Wicket application the Spring context gets started from the dependency and the REST interface is available for the ionic clients. My issue is that I cannot tie the Wicket application to that existing Spring context. Wicket just wants to start a new Spring context with the same beans.
Now I can access the beans through some static methods from the spring context, but I want to use the `@SpringBean` annotation as in a regular Wicket+Spring application.
Is there a solution for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wicket does not start any Spring context, as long as you don't instruct it to do so. Are you using the filter init-param "contextConfigLocation"?

When you just register a Spring injector inside your application, it should  pick up the default Spring web context (it uses Spring's WebApplicationContextUtils#getRequiredWebApplicationContext()):

```
getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
```

Comment: In addition SpringComponentInjector has constructors which accept  ApplicationContent instances (https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/686058119dd795b3de7f2016e3e64fb8f025f813/wicket-spring/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/spring/injection/annot/SpringComponentInjector.java#L90). So you can pass even sub-contexts.

Comment: I think this is what I need, the constructor that has a context as parameter. The default one doesn't find it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your Spring backend is a web application, not just a java module. You cannot not (should not) have this web application as a dependency to an other web application (your new Wicket module).
You should probably move your shared business logic in a new java module. This new java module can be a dependency of your 2 web applications (Spring backend and Wicket).

An other solution would be to have 3 web applications. Spring facade, Wicket facade and Spring backend. Spring facade and Wicket facade, would just be some simple REST Controller which would redirect the request to the Spring backend to execute the business logic.